# Health Swap Mechanic in HearthStone

Tags: hearthstone

I want to understand how the health swap mechanic works when using the [Reversing switch](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Reversing_Switch) in HearthStone.

If i played [Cogmaster](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Cogmaster) Followed by a mech to activate his effect, then switched his attack and health with [Reversing switch](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Reversing_Switch) , would he have the buffed number or the original swapped?
[image][image]

If so, when the mech is destroyed would the health go back to the original?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reversing Switch will use the buffed stats of 3/2, boosting Cogmaster to 4/3.  In effect, the Cogmaster's buff will be applied twice.  The mechanics of this can be found in the description of [Crazed Alchemist](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Crazed_Alchemist#Notes).

> The Battlecry works by taking the minion's Attack and Health values, and creating an enchantment specifically granting the minion the opposite values. Because this enchantment is created based upon the minion's current values, any bonuses such as other enchantments and auras (such as the one granted by Stormwind Champion) are incorporated into the enchantment. The enchantment will sit 'on top of' previous enchantments, overriding their effects on the minion's Health.
>
> However, because auras are automatically re-applied following each game event, once the new enchantment is granted, any aura effects will be reapplied, on top of the Alchemist's enchantment. This allows minions with Crazed Alchemist's buff to effectively benefit from auras twice - once through their inclusion in the Alchemist's buff, and then again through being reapplied after the buff has been granted.

When all mechs are destroyed, the Cogmaster would revert to 2/3 (assuming no injuries)

> Because the Alchemist's buff overrides any previously applied stat-modifying buffs and sets the minion's stats to specific values, the expiry of any previously applied buffs will not affect the minion's stats. For example, a minion affected by Abusive Sergeant's Battlecry which is then buffed by a Crazed Alchemist will lose the Sergeant's buff at the end of the turn, but will not lose any Attack or Health as a result.

Comment: Tip: This also works with things like murlocks that buff each other. You can attack with your murlock and then swap it's health to it's heightened attack power, and then the attack power buff transfers after the affect is done.

Comment: These sorts of buffs also work wonders against Thaddius, the Naxxramas boss, because he auto-fires his stat-shifting hero power every turn.

Answer (score 3):

If you swapped his health when he was a 3/2 (from the buff), he would turn into a 4/3 (with the buff).  If he lost the buff he would then turn into a 2/3.

I had a similar situation with another card and that's how it worked.  I can't remember what card but it was definitely pretty much the same scenario.